# TypeLoadException using WinRT Brokered Component

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-component

I am building a Windows Store App using a [brokered component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn630195.aspx). The brokered component is meant to enable interaction with an RFID reader on the device. When I try to initialize an instance of the class exposed by the brokered component, I received a `System.TypeLoadException` with the message `Could not find or load a type. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131522).`

I'm working against a clean installation of Windows 8.1 Professional on two different tablet devices. Both are currently experiencing this issue. The solution has worked in the past; something I've done recently must be causing this. I've also verified that the RFID reader can be accessed using a sample application provided by the hardware vendor.

My Package.appxmanifest file looks similar to this:

```
<Package ...>
  ...
  <Extensions>
    <Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
      <InProcessServer>
        <Path>clrhost.dll</Path>
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="MyApp.RFID.Component.RfidDevice" ThreadingModel="STA">
          <ActivatableClassAttribute Name="DesktopApplicationPath" Type="string" Value="C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\RFID" />
        </ActivatableClass>
      </InProcessServer>
    </Extension>
  </Extensions>
</Package>
```

The solution is being built to target an x86 platform. I've registered my components on the target device under `C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\RFID` using the following commands (per this [whitepaper](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2014/04/14/cheat-sheet-for-using-brokered-windows-runtime-components-for-side-loaded-windows-store-apps/)):

`icacls . /T /grant "ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES":RX`

`regsvr32 MyApp.RFID.Proxy.dll`

I've installed the Visual Studio 2013 x86 Redistributable Package on the target device. I've also placed an additional dependency .dll in the same directory, just as I have been doing during all of my development.

Some other things I've tried:

- Using %PROGRAMFILES% instead of `C:\Program Files (x86)` as the value for the ActivatableClassAttribute in the manifest.
- Using 'STA', 'MTA', and 'Both' as the threading models.
- Added a trailing slash to the ActivatableClassAttribute value path.
- Completely uninstalled everything and tried again from scratch.
- Explicitly add an empty default constructor to the `RfidDevice` class.

Comment: Were you able to generate the winmd file? The winmd file should be in the same path where the proxy is.

Comment: Yes, I believe the winmd files were being generated. However, as the brokered component was being very unstable I decided to replace them with a windows service using interprocess communication. Therefore, I'm no longer troubleshooting this issue.